# Airflow warning "Set 1 task instances to state=None as their associated DagRun was not in RUNNING state"

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

When starting a new DAG without any previous run, we get this exception below, how to fix it?

```
airflow-scheduler    | [2021-06-06 16:41:07,363] {scheduler_job.py:855} WARNING - Set 1 task instances to state=None as their associated DagRun was not in RUNNING state
```

Comment: Can you please add you DAG definition (at least default_args and schedule_interval) + airflow version and executor?

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, problem solved, we don't know why but default values has been added to timestamp columns in our MySQL database and were sources of inconsistencies.